# How to make every content of a Relative Layout clickable in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, onclicklistener, clickable

I have a layout:

```html
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="227dp"
        android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:duplicateParentState="false"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:id ="@+id/relLay">

        <Gallery
            android:id = "@+id/gvImage"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="2dp"
            android:clickable="true"/>


    <TextView
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gvImage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/gvImage"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gvImage"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=SOMETHING"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/favorite_check"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@null"/>

        <TextView
            android:background="#CCCCCC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rate: ?"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gvImage"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

And it is called by a fragment class,

```html
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_result, container, false);
        Gallery gallery = (Gallery)view.findViewById(R.id.gvImage);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));

        
        return view;
    }
```

I want to do something like, if I click any item inside of RelativeLayout of that xml file it will do something like, will go to another class or Toast text.
How will I do this?

Comment: Did you even google? Where is your problem?

Comment: You also have typo's in the xml...

Comment: Yes, I had tried to call method but faced problem with GalleryView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement onClickListener to each and every View.

Simplest way will be

```
<TextView
            android:background="#CCCCCC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rate: ?"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gvImage"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            onclick="executeTextViewClick" />
```

And in java class declare a function as follows.

```
public void executeTextViewClick(View view){

//Toast here or navigate to other activity 

}
```

Comment: It is working for every element except <Gallery />. If I call method from this part only one image is showing in GalleryView not all images. Is there any solution?

Comment: For Gallery you cant do this simply. You need to use CustomAdapter