# View is not responsive behind a gridview

Tags: android, gridview, onclicklistener, clickable

I'm having a problem with a `OnClickListener` on a `Relative Layout`. The `Relative Layout` has a `GridView` inside, and I'm not able to make the clicks pass through the `GridView`.

What I would like to achieve is that the whole `Relative Layout` is responsive to clicks. Without the `GridView` it obviously works like a charm. But if I add the `GridView` with some elements, the whole area of the `GridView` becomes unresponsive. Only above the `GridView` it remains responsive.

So I tried everything: setting the `GridView` to don't allow touch, to be not clickable to pass it to the `ParentView`, but without any result.

Does anybody of you have an idea what I could try ?

Thanks a lot for any help!
Cheers

Comment: have u tried disabling the gridView? `setEnabled(false);` With that it should not respond to clicks

Comment: Did u try Onitem click listener on gridview to perform the same operation like on the relative layout.

Comment: Thank you guys! I did already try setEnabled(false); that doesn't work. Only setting it's visibility to GONE would work...

I could try to workaround with the OnItemClick but, that's gonna be a terrible implementation as I have 10 of these relative layouts inside my activity with different tags, and handle that would just be quite ugly...

That is the last solution I would like to implement.

Answer (score 0):

For GridView you are using an adapter and you have to use gridView.setOnItemClickListener() to make items clickable.

Comment: I do not want clickable Items. I want to pass the clicks to the parent View. The grid view should not be clickable at all.

Comment: Define a method and call it from Relative Layout onClick and GridView onItemClick- It will work.   BTW, I faced same problem few months ago, got this solution, accepted the solution and worked. Let me add something, because of using adapter I had to use that and didn't get any better solution. Here is the link of that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836019/how-to-make-every-content-of-a-relative-layout-clickable-in-android